# getScript displaying loaded data in a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, getscript

I'm trying to load a video stream provided by a 3rd party into my site. The file linking to the stream is provided as a js file and simply writes out `document.write('iframe code...')`. As the stream is domain protected so the js file has to be referenced.

This lead me to the `$.ajax` / `dataType: script` and `$.getScript` options. The following leaves the target div blank

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

var stream = 'http://live.streamsupplier.com/se8ilyjs/'; 
$("#cam").click(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        url: stream,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#cam').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You are falling foul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) because the URL your are requesting is external from your site. You will need to use a server-side proxy to get the script, and then call this local URL from your jQuery code to insert the script.